# Discord.py raw_reaction_add wont find member

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wrote this code within the Discord.py API version 1.4 and everything works fine.
Now i tried to import it into my new 1.5 code and its not working anymore.
"404 no member found."

I couldnt find any changes in the APi, so im curios why its not working anymore.

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 768180630218342411:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, bot.guilds)
        if payload.emoji.name == 'testemoji':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='testrolle')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'emojitest':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='rolletest')
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)

        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            #member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print("done")
            else:
                print("404 no member found")
        else:
            print("404 no group found")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the new version of discord.py, which is 1.5.1, there is an update about [`Intents`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#intents). Probably that's why you couldn't get the members by using `discord.utils.get`. You need to define the `Intents` at the beginning of your code, before you define the `bot = commands.Bot(prefix='')`:

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', intents=intents)
```

Comment: Now i get the following error:
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
And i set the bots permissions to Admin, with Oauth.

Comment: [HasteBin](https://haste.athion.net/ameqejeyov.py)

Thats it buddy.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what's the problem.

Comment: its fine, ill figure it out oneday. :D
id like to vote your answer up, but i dont have enoug rep. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Nurqm has sent you on the right path. The code is right. You should also read more on intents [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#need-members-intent).

From your comments, it seems you have not enabled intents from the discord website for [applications](https://discord.com/developers/applications). Intents needs to be enabled there as well [Link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents).

Adding the code from Nurqm.

```
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.all()
...

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', intents=intents)
```